# Is there any way to check java process state history in linux and, what event changed the state of that process.

Tags: java, linux, kill-process, thread-dump, jstack

My java process in Linux changes its state to Traced/Stopped (T state when I check using top command in Linux)

Empty thread dump is getting created. (Have tried jstack, jstack -F, kill -3).
(Checked the catalina.out logs as well, no thread dump)

Heap dump generated is also empty.

Memory and CPU consumption is also fine.

Java Version - 1.6_85
Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Is there any way to debug this issue.

Comment: Do you have exceptions in the logfiles?